# If $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of $G$ and $G/H \cong K$, does this imply that $G/K \cong H$?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

> If $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of $G$ and $G/H \cong K$, does this imply that $G/K \cong H$?

I wasn't able to find a counterexample or to prove that the implication is true. I would appreciate any help with this question. Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean that $G/H$ is isomorphic to $K$? Because I don't think they can ever be equal.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, sorry. I edited it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Here is how to ask in MSE https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: @newton-laws When trying to prove that the implication is true, I couldn't make any non-trivial progress. On the other hand, I couldn't find any counterexamples. I've realized, for example, that if $G$ is cyclic then the implication is true, but I didn't consider this to be that relevant to include it in the question.

Comment: A lot of users do not read the comments before downvoting or voting to close; therefore, I suggest you [edit] the question to include your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: Exactly, @RaduMoga, a lot of people won't hessitate before downvoting your question or even closing it. So, it would be better if you included some of your insights, or any approach you think may work.

Comment: As written, the answer is no, and you can find an abelian counterexample of order $8$, which if I’m not mistaken is the smallest possible order of a counterexample. It would be true if $H\cap K=\{e\}$, because then you get $G=H\times K$ (internal direct sum).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you for pointing out the extra condition which makes it true.

Comment: @RaduMoga: **an** extra condition making it true, not “the” extra condition to make it true.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counterexample: take $G=Q=\{ 1, -1, i, -i, j, -j, k, -k\}$ the quaternion group of order $8$. Take $H=\langle i \rangle$ and $K=Z(Q)=\{1, -1\}$. $G/K$ in non-cyclic, where $H$ is.